# Why all addresses 127.0.0.x are redirecting to localhost?

Tags: localhost, apache2

I hope you're doing great!

I'm working with Apache2 on Windows (not all Wamp, just Apache2) and I usually don't have problems, but today I wanted to add a new virtual host and I told myself I'm gonna do it on the 127.0.0.2 address as the 127.0.0.1 is already taken by localhost (folder Apache2/htdocs). But this address (127.0.0.2) redirects also to localhost and everey adress (127.0.0.x) so on even the last (127.0.0.255).

Does anyone had this problem before and knows how to resolve it ? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Just for you to know I didn't changed much things to add virtual host (I mean normal changes). Plus I don't know if this problem was here before or not as I didn't have to check other addresses (127.0.0.x).

Thanks to anyone reading this and trying to help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with this solution even if it's not the most optimized I think :

In the file C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf at line 60, I changed from "Listen 80" to "Listen 127.0.0.1:80" and it resolved my problem.

Hope it will help someone that will face the same problem ;)

Have a good day !